# Black stripes on third screen

Tags: wpf, nvidia, artifacts

I have three screens, connected to two nVidia 560Ti cards, and when I move my WPF application to the third screen, connected to the second card, click on a item in a treeview, I get these black stripes across the app.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Msu3v.png]

The black lines disappear if I move the application to either of the other screens.
I have already changed the graphics card, with no luck, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the nvidia drivers, but still no luck.

Occasionally the third screen turn black, music stutters, and the two other screens flash black, before they all come back up, and I get a "Graphics driver has crashed, but recovered" bubble on the taskbar. I'm quite positive these two are part of the same problem, but since I only get errors on my WPF applications, I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the crashes, or if it's something else.

edit: I did some more testing, by setting my third display as my main display, and now the artifacts only appear on both screen 1 and 2.
Meaning: If I have 3 screens, with screen 1 as my main screen, artifacts happens on screen 3. The same happens if screen 2 is main. If screen 3 is main, on the other hand, artifacts happen on screen 1 and 2. However, this is only true if screen 3 is in the middle, meaning I move the application only one screen to get to either screen 1 or 2. If I move my application through screen 2 to get to screen 1, the artifacts don't happen.

Comment: Holy crap... I come to read this question.... then I realize... I have 3 monitors too and 2 Nvidia cards (GT730) so they're crap, but great for "business quality". I see exactly the same kind of black lines. Felt so alone. I really hope this is only a graphics card issue and that my customers are not going to have this happen...

Comment: I have the same problem with an Intel HD Graphics card, using Windows 7. It's the first time, my third monitor has any display issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to

- update the driver
- [reduce the 3D acceleration / write combining settings](http://www.tweakguides.com/NVFORCE_6.html)

[image]

### Windows property dialog:

[**On a computer that is running Windows XP**](http://navozhdeniye.narod.ru/263391.htm) (link includes W2k and Vista)

> 1. Right-click the desktop, and then click Properties on the menu.
> 2. Click the Settings tab, and then click Advanced.
> 3. Click the Troubleshoot tab.
> 4. Move the Hardware Acceleration slider until it is one notch to the right of None, the Basic acceleration setting.
> 5. Click OK, and then click Close.
>
> If the issue is resolved when you set the Graphics Hardware Acceleration slider to None or Basic, contact your hardware manufacturer to inquire about how to obtain and install the latest video driver for your video adapter.
>
> If you have installed the latest video driver for your video adapter and you continue to experience graphic issues with the Graphics Hardware Acceleration slider set to Full, repeat the steps in this article, except move the Graphics Hardware Acceleration slider one notch to the left until the issue no longer occurs.

Comment: I have the newest driver from nvidia. I can not disable Write combining because the option is not present.

Comment: @AkselK: I suggest you don't disable it then :) Just hoping something will help you leverage your graphics card to the fullest